# Web photo gallery software

Tags: web-apps, images, gallery

I have 250GB of scanned images arranged in nested folders. The structure is something like:

Subject Folder -> Title Folder -> 001.jpg, 002.jpg, ...

I want to convert these folders into web photo gallery with something like:

- Folder hierarchy in left pane (in something like tree view)
- Images in right pane (may have thumbnail, book view or original image view)

I can make the images in Linux or Windows server.

Can anyone suggest a web application (or something like WordPress plugins) that can serve the purpose?

<sub>I don't want to "input" the images one by one into the software, but just point it to the file folder.</sub>